# Зачем Repository Interface В паттерн на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php8

Доброго времени суток друзя.

Хотел бы узнать конкретную причину использования интерфейсов в паттерне `Repository`.

Вот простой паттерн для наглядности.

**RepositoryInterface**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Repository;

interface UserRepositoryInterface extends BaseRepositoryInterface
{
    public function getByEmail(string $email);
}
```

**Repository** для самого интерфейса.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Repository\Eloquent;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Repository\UserRepositoryInterface;

final class UserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function __construct( User $model )
    {}

    public function getByEmail(string $email): User | bool
    {
        $user = $this->model->where('email', $email);

        if($user->exists())
            return $user->first();

        return false;
    }
}
```

**А теперь биндим**

```
$this->app->bind(UserRepositoryInterface::class, UserRepository::class);
```

Ну и напоследок уже делаем инекцию в классе где нам нужно будет. И оно выглядит так.

```
final class UserController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly UserRepositoryInterface $userRepository
    ){}

    public function profile(UsersGetRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->userRepository->getByEmail(auth()->user()->email);
    }
}
```

Наконец то дошли до самой сути вопроса. Мы для каждого репозитория создаем для него интерфейс.

Какое реальное приемущество оно нам дает?

Веть мы например в нашем примере можем делать инекцию самого репозитория. Примерно так.

```
public function __construct(
    private readonly UserRepository $userRepository
){}
```

И дальше аналогично работать с ним.

Что тогда будет не так? Или где мы можетм столкнутя с проблемой?

Дайте свое мнение?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Всё до банального просто: **soliD**.

Представим, что в проекте несколько вариаций репозиторев: один достаёт данные из БД, другой - из памяти, третий - из файла, четвёртый - через API, пятый - из космоса.

В какой-то конкретный момент времени мы не знаем какой репозиторий будем применять. Это будет определяться, например, в конфиге приложения, а может и вовсе динамическим выбором суперадминистратором из интерфейса (ну мало ли). В итоге, при подстановке интерфейса в контроллер, какой бы репозиторий в любой момент времени не был бы выбран - работа приложения не нарушится. А вот если будет выбран, например `UserFileRepository`, а контроллер будет ожидать конкретный - то приложение рухнет.

Comment: Нет, я немного про другое, в этом паттерне например в моем примере, мы для каждой модели создаём РЕПО, и его интерфейс. Ваш пример немного другой, и это понятно

Comment: @Anonymous перечитайте ещё раз. Я как раз ответил на ваш вопрос.....По факту, интерфейс создаётся не на каждый репозиторий, а на каждую группу одинаковых репозиторев....... Если в проекте предполагается **всегда железно 1000000%** применение только одного вида репозитория в каждом из контроллеров - то интерфейс, конечно, не нужен.. Это не железное правило и нужно применять это обдуманно........Ларавель предполагает, что могут быть ситуации разноплановых классов. Поэтому предлагает сразу делать SOLODно. Чтобы потом проблем не возникло при расширении

Comment: @Anonymous что я подразумеваю под "создаётся на каждую группу одинаковых репозиторев" --- это как раз описано во втором абзаце ответа. Т.е. userRepository может иметь множество вариаций хранения/добычи информации. И контроллеру должно быть плевать кто это, главное, чтобы соблюдалась одна и та же логика для всех этих вариаций. Имплементирование интерфейса для всех этих вариаций гарантирует, что все они будут иметь нужные методы для использования, т.к. имплементирование автоматом принуждает определить логику для методов

Comment: Я вас понял, вы мой вопрос нет. Могу ли я не написать вообще никаого интерфейса, например для простого репоситории? И чем оно будет не правильно? Если я знаю что оно точно не измениться ? 
Или хоть голый интерфейс нужно писать ?

Comment: можете не написать вообще никакого интерфейса. ничем не будет неправильно. Интерфейс нужен чтобы обеспечить различные реализации без общего наследования. Если реализация гарантированно одна и никакое расширение не предполагается, то смысла заводить интерфейсы нет.

Comment: @Anonymous ответ на эти вопросы есть в моём комментарии, который вы, почему-то, решили не читать. Причём там даже жирным выделено